# How can i create a separate results window in pascal?

Tags: window, pascal

at the time i am in the process of learning pascal but i have some question that google can't answer, so i am trying to do a program that analyzes how much overweight does a person have relating to a set of data. the thing is that i don;t know how to make another window or to clear the window so that only the results appear in the screen, My teacher wants something like this (Don't mind the spanish ;D ) :

And Here is my code so far:

```
Program AddNums(output);

uses crt;

var
  s, b, a, v: integer;

begin
  clrscr;
  GotoXY(20, 1);
  writeln('Ejercicio 2 - Actividad 2');

  GotoXY(25, 3);
  writeln('Calculadora de Pesos');
  write('Introduce la cantidad de personas para analizar sus pesos: ');
  readln(s);

  for a := 1 to s do
  begin
    writeln('Introduzca el peso de la persona numero', a, ':');
    readln(v)
  end;

  clrscr;
  if (v <= 90) then
    write('Cantidad de personas con Sobrepeso: ...........', v + 1);
  else if (v <= 30) then
    write('Cantidad de personas con Bajo Peso: ...........', v + 1);
  else if (v <= 30 AND v >= 90) then
    write('Cantidad de Personas con Peso normal: ...........', v + 1);
  else
    write('null');

end.


And this
```

is the error that i am encountering right now

```
(35,4) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found
```

Fatal: Compilation aborted

Hope you guys help me !!

Comment: I don't understand why you ask how to clear the screen, as you already seem to know `clrscr`

Comment: Please also always mark the line of error with a comment, as line numbers are not visible in your post.

Comment: Aside: `v <= 30 AND v >= 90` can't possibly happen.  Maybe you meant `OR` and proper parentheses?  Actually, your whole `IF` sequence is wrong.  The first condition will mask the second, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The last few lines of your code need to be corrected as shown below in order to compile, and then you need to check that the code does what you want it to.  The program should then compile, and assuming you are running it in an environment like Lazarus, the IDE for Free Pascal, it will appear in a console window as @TomBrunberg has commentedThere were basically two problems with it:

- The first three `else`s were preceded by a semicolon (`;`).  That is a syntax error.  Each `else` is part of an `if ... then ...else` block.  The only circumstances when a semicolon is permitted is when it is inside a compound statement, for example a `begin ... end` block, as in

```
      begin
        DoSomething;
      end
    else
      write('Cantidad de personas con Sobrepeso: ...........', v + 1)
```

- The other problem was that you had

`(v <= 30 AND v >= 90)`

The **syntax** problem with that is that in Pascal, `and` has higher operator precedence than `<=` so the compiler tries, and fails, to evaluate `30 and v`.  It fails because the result should be of type Boolean, which it cannot be.  To avoid that problem, you need to close the parenthesese, like this

`(v <= 30) and (v >= 90)`

Then, the expressions on either side of the `and` both evaluate to Booleans, so the compiler can successfully combine then with `and`.  **However**, as @Tom has pointed out in a comment, the combined expression can never evaluate to True because `v` cannot be less or equal to 30 and greater or equal to 90 at the same time:  perhaps you meant OR?

Corrected code

```
  if (v <= 90) then
    write('Cantidad de personas con Sobrepeso: ...........', v + 1)
  else if (v <= 30) then
    write('Cantidad de personas con Bajo Peso: ...........', v + 1)
  else if (v <= 30) AND (v >= 90) then
    write('Cantidad de Personas con Peso normal: ...........', v + 1)
  else
    write('null');
  readln;
```

The `readln` at the end makes the program wait for you to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that it stays on-screen long enough for you to see it - without the `readln`, the console window would just close and vanish.

Comment: Has this answered your q?